# Save objects in Java HttpServlet Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

During processing the doGet/doPost methods in my servlet, I made some Java objects. But unfortunately, all of the created objects will be gone when the application instance is shutdowned. Is there anyway that I save it and use for for later requests, beside the datastore option, which does not work well in my case because my objects are not supported properties (according to error log on google app engine).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use appengine memcache service. Memcache is managed independent of the application instances and is available across all application instances. But memcache is not very reliable and your data could be swiped off by appengine.

So if you can't reconstruct the objects reliably when they are not available in memcache, you may need to look at persistent storage options like datastore.

Answer (score 0):

What error were you seeing in your logs?

One standard approach to this problem is to serialize your object, using either Java's [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) facilities, or something like JSON (e.g., [GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)), then stash it in the datastore.

Treating memcache as anything other than a short-term cache is risky.